# Datatables JS - Is there a HTML 5 way to order data by specifying data-order parameter on <th>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to do something like this:

```
<th data-order='[ "true", "asc" ]'>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
```

I know I can specify the HTML 5 attribute at the `<table>` level and that works in most cases. However I need to be able to specify on the table header level - is there a way to do that?

I know you can do it when you initialize the table - but my initialization code is very generic so I don't want to mess it up with this type of logic.

I know I can have a custom initialization just for the table where I want to to this custom `<th>` order - but I am looking for a cleaner solution to do it.

That is why I am asking if there is a HTML 5 way to do it?

As a last resort I will write an extension or modify the core so it reads the parameters and understands it - but I just want to know if there is already an HTML 5 way to do it?

Resources to consider:

[HTML5 data-* attributes - table options](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-options.html)

[HTML5 data-* attributes - cell data](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)

Comment: Well, HTML5 doesn't have a means to order data. There were propositions, but those were scrapped because of lack of implementation. In other words, if you want to sort a table, you'll have to do it yourself; there is no HTML5 way to do it.

Comment: I understand. They have data-orderable="false' - you can specify it as an attribute on <th data-orderable="false'> - and it will do the trick. You can also specify  data-order='[[7, "desc"], ["9", "asc" ]]' on the <table> level - and it will read and know to sort it this way. Datatable JS implemented quite some way to do stuff via HTML 5 attributes which is very good. You can even sort multiple column using HTML 5 data-* attribute - my sub question to this all is whether there is a known way to do it via <th> tags. This is not far from what is already doable

Comment: Let's think about this one <table data-order='[[8, "desc"], ["10", "asc" ]]'>.... On initialization, .js library looks for any data-attributes (in our case on the <table > level) - then it calls the same API it does when if you were initializing it using Javascript or JQuery. HTML 5 is just sort of an Interface - no more no less.

Comment: Datatables is just a jQuery plugin.. you are talking about functionality specific to that plugin, not to html5

Comment: HTML 5 provides access to the same API plugin offers. It is just limited in this case.

Comment: Not sure why you are trying to do this at TH level. What if multiple TH elements defined the sort order? Then you have ambiguous `order` definition and need a tie breaker (first wins, last wins, random wins, king george wins, etc.). What specifically are you trying to achieve and why isn't the current method working for you?

Comment: Normally - when the amount of columns stay the same - that is the way to go. However in my case number of columns change. I have a table where the first 2 columns and the last 3 stay the same - but the middles columns change. Sometimes there may be 4 columns to represent the view - but sometimes there could be 3, 5 or 6.  So -order='[[8, "desc"], ["10", "asc" ]]' - this would be only true when I have 5 columns. Once I have a view that have 3 - they table will throw an error because there is no index 10 so it can't sort. I can hack a goofy logic to make it work but that would be a hack

Comment: So in my case I need a way to specify the column index or mark a certain column - <th> as orderable then specify Asc or Desc. Sure I can have a function that would figure out how many columns are based on that will set the indexes here data-order='[[8, "desc"], ["10", "asc" ]]' - there are a lot of non legit way to solve it - that is not what I am after though. Sure I can also use different table initialization and structure it differently - all is doable. My point is to find the best and cleanest way which I find to be the one as suggested.

Comment: In regards to the logic - I see your point. Keep in mind that Datatables JS already dealing with that. When data- attribute is specified - they likely just override what they had there at the moment. Logic does not have to be complicated. You can just give priorities - if it  is declared withing the JS code - set that. If you detect that also it is declared as an attribute withing <table> tag - then that is the one to go (this tag is a global to the whole table). They currently deal with data-orderable which is also could be set withing the <table> tag - so that would not be something new

Answer (score 2):

No.

Instead, you may specify default sort order in the `table` element using `data-order`.

In the `th` (column header) elements you may define these sort options:

- `data-orderable` whether column can be sorted
- `data-orderData` if you want secondary, tertiary, etc., sorting on this column
- `data-orderDataType` data type for column with respect to sorting (determines the comparator)
- `data-orderSequence` default asc or desc order for the column

See API docs for the jQuery datatables plugin:

using data attributes for options: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-options.html

options for columns:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/